# Coordinate free computation of functional derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $F(g(f))$
be a functional that sends functions of a vector variable (from $n$-dimensional vector space) to $\mathbb R$.

$g$
is some function of scalar valued functions $f$.

I'm interested in a coordinate free calculation of the first and second derivatives of functionals on the spaces of real valued functions of a vector variable, where the vector space dimension can be more than 3.

It can be [shown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Formula) using vector calculus that the first (order) functional derivative $\partial F$
is equal to the partial derivative of $g$
with respect to $f$
minus the divergence of the gradient of $g$.

\begin{gather*}
F=\int {f(x)} ^{4} dx^{4} \\
\partial F= \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{f}} - \nabla \cdot\nabla g(f).
\end{gather*}

Divergence of the gradient should be equal to $4$, and if I plug in the above functional into the formula on Wikipedia it should work just as well for 4d and I get the result: $ \partial F=−12f^{3}$.

Can I just plug this into the formula again and get the second derivative of the functional?

Comment: Though I'd also appreciate if anyone can tell me what the second derivative is using any method, component or otherwise so I can check if my attmpt makes any sense